# Get the url of the website the user is about to open?

Tags: google-chrome

I am just developing an extension to kill time so I was wondering is it possible get the url of a website the person is about to open? like say suppose I open up a new tab and type in google.com. It is possible for me to get url as soon as I hit enter or go?